# Odoo api.depends and non stored field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Lets say I have a One2Many field which is computed and not stored. Now I have a Boolean field which is computed and stored. The compute method of the Boolean field has the decorator api.depends('non_stored_field'). The non stored field would be the One2Many field in my case. Does the function still trigger when the One2Many field changes?

Comment: Good question. Have you already wrote some code and tested? My best quess is that it won't be triggered. But you know for sure when you write a little test module and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested it but it doesnt get triggered. I thought that someone here knew an expected behaviour of my case but it seems that even the devs dont have a clue what is going on.